# AJV JsonSchema validator reports seemingly incorrect error

Tags: node.js, jsonschema, ajv

I'm using AJV to validate a HTTP request payload against a schema. However, I see an error reported that I was not expecting. This is a code example to demonstrate the issue:

```
const schema = {
  type: 'array',
  minItems: 1,
  items: {
    anyOf: [
      {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          op: {
            enum: ['replace']
          },
          path: {
            type: 'string',
            pattern: '/data/to/foo/bar',
          },
          value: {
            type: 'string',
          },
        },
      },{
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          op: {
            enum: ['replace']
          },
          path: {
            type: 'string',
            pattern: '/data/to/baz',
          },
          value: {
            type: 'object',
            required: ['foo', 'bar'],
            properties: {
              foo: {
                type: 'string',
              },
              bar: {
                type: 'string',
              },
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },
}

const validator = new ajv()

const compiledValidator = validator.compile(schema)
  const data = [
  { // this object should pass
    op: 'replace',
    path: '/data/to/foo/bar',
    value: 'foo',
  },
  { // this object should fail in the `value` mismatch (missing required attribute)
    op: 'replace',
    path: '/data/to/baz',
    value: {
      foo: 'bar',
    },
  },
]

compiledValidator(data)

console.log(compiledValidator.errors)
```

The schema defines a number of objects to which an incoming list of data objects should match. The first data item matches the schema (first item schema), however the second data item misses a required attribute (`bar`) in the `value` object.

When I run the above code I get the following output:

```
[
  {
    instancePath: '/1/path',
    schemaPath: '#/items/anyOf/0/properties/path/pattern',
    keyword: 'pattern',
    params: { pattern: '/data/to/foo/bar' },
    message: 'must match pattern "/data/to/foo/bar"'
  },
  {
    instancePath: '/1/value',
    schemaPath: '#/items/anyOf/1/properties/value/required',
    keyword: 'required',
    params: { missingProperty: 'bar' },
    message: "must have required property 'bar'"
  },
  {
    instancePath: '/1',
    schemaPath: '#/items/anyOf',
    keyword: 'anyOf',
    params: {},
    message: 'must match a schema in anyOf'
  }
]
```

I understand the 2nd and the 3rd (last) errors. However, The first error seems to indicate that the `path` doesn't match `path` requirements of the first item schema. It is true that the 2nd data item doesn't match the 1st schema item but I don't seem to understand how it is relevant. I would assume that the error would be focused around the `value`, not the `path` since it matches on the `path` schemas.

Is there a way to get the error reporting more focused around the errors that matter?

Comment: I think it _does_ matter. It shows why the second instance item doesn't match the first `anyOf` option. Without this error, you may think it matches that option, in which case you'd be confused about the last error.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, and that is what is confusing to me because the `path` of the second data item matches the second schema item. So, why is it reported as an error... As far as matching goes, the neither `path` of both data items have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for the evaluator to know whether you intended the first "anyOf" subschema to match or the second, so the most useful thing to do is to show you all the errors.

It can be confusing because you don't need to resolve *all* the errors, just some of them, which is why [some implementations also offer a heirarchical error format](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.12.4.3) to make it more easy to see relationships like this. Maybe if you request that `ajv` implement more of these error formats, it will happen :)

Answer (score 1):

You can see that all of the errors pertain to the second item in the data by looking at the `instancePath` for each error, which all start with `/1`.  This is the location *within the data* that generated the error.

So let's look at the second item and compare it against the schema.

```js
{ // this object should fail in the `value` mismatch (missing required attribute)
  op: 'replace',
  path: '/data/to/baz',
  value: {
    foo: 'bar',
  },
}
```

The schema says that an item should either (from the `anyOf`) have

- `path: '/data/to/foo/bar'` and `value: { type: 'string' }`, or
- `path: '/data/to/baz'` and `value: { required: [ 'foo', 'bar' ] }`

The reported errors are:

1. The first case fails because `path` is wrong.
2. The second case fails because `/value/bar` is not present.
3. The last error is just the `anyOf` reporting that none of the options passed.